# How to make a bar chart not group things by day

Tags: excel

I've got the following table

[image]

What I want do is create a bar chart and to have 5 different bars, each one with a height of 2. The issue is that, because there are 2 items that are on the 04/01/2022 then my chart groups them together. Is there a way to make Excel say "Separate that single bar into 2 because the times are different?

This is what Excel currently creates for me

[image]

I know that this type of chart doesn't make much sense right now but it does on the bigger project that I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a pivot table, it will look like this:
[image]